# What is the purpose of "X-NginX-Proxy"

Tags: nginx

Many [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22X-NginX-Proxy%22&oq=%22X-NginX-Proxy%22) around the internet is using "X-NginX-Proxy"

Nowhere can I find a proper description of its purpose or why one would use it, apart from that it relates to using nginx as a proxy?

Example:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name forum.example.org;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
...
```

Comment: Looks like it was in a popular tutorial and everyone went and copied it. The endpoint you're proxying to could use it to detect that it's behind a proxy, but it's not any sort of standard thing, nor is it likely to be necessary in most cases.